# Plastic deformation soft body / cloth pressure / dynamic paint / waves

Tags: cloth-simulation, soft-body, dynamic-paint

I want to simulat the rolling of dough and achieve something like this: https://media.giphy.com/media/uq8Nqas3wsCITJ1MiD/giphy.gif

I have tried soft body, cloth pressure,  dynamic painting, waves but all have at least one serious limitation.

My requirements are:

1. The dough conforms to the roller's surface and receives plastic deformation
2. The dough should be elastic at the front of the roller and behave like the total volume stays roughly the same.

What is the best approach to tackle this?

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you should cheat and use shapekeys?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Just as @moonboots says, maybe you should cheat? The question would be, is your goal to somehow create something like this and intentionally wanting to achieve this with soft body physics... or is your only goal to get something similar to this no matter how? Because I would strongly suspect the reference is "cheated" as well.

Comment: I need to impress the exact shape of the cylinder (which may include other geometry and may even be conical). The above characteristics of the rotating "cylinder" will vary in time so it would be neat to just be able to impress the shape.  Other than that, @lemon's suggestion or even shapkeys (moonboots) should work

Answer (score 5):

That can be geometry nodes:

[image]

Starting from the undeformed dough shape, make another one flat but with extact same vertices.

[image]

Then, test the dough vertices position compared to a given point on the belt (here y=1, for simplicity).

From that mix the original shape positions to the flat one, using a float curve to manage the transition between the two.

[image]

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Lattice cage that looks like a funnel, it will deform the ball, you'll need to keyframe its scale so that it stays round:

[image]

File: [image]